# Stop a webpage from opening before a certain time

Tags: html

I have a little homework webpage. Each week I add a new webpage. Each webpage "switches off" at a certain time with a little script which disables the send button.

Each week's homework is opened from my Leitfile.html which is just a lot of buttons linked to each week's webpage.

With help from here, I kind of reversed the "switch off" script. It switches the latest button in the Leitfile.html on at a certain time.

For example, this is week 16. The button for week16 will "switch on" at midday today. Before then, the link is empty. You can't open the link from the Leitfile.html

However, I can simply click week15, then I have 18BEwW15.html. Change the 5 to a 6 in the browser and I have 18BEwW16.html open.

How can I make 18BEwW16.html comepletely "unopenable" until a set time?

Switch on (works on the Leitfile.html link button)

```
<script>
var linkMsg = document.getElementById("link");
    var kickoff = new Date("February 26, 2019 06:00:00");
    //

    function checkForValidation() {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        //
        if (currentDate > kickoff) {
           linkMsg.innerHTML = "<a href='17week7.html'>学期第七周 week7</a>";
        } 
    }
    //
    window.onload = checkForValidation();
    </script>
```

Switch off:

```
<script> var expMsg = document.getElementById("expireMsg");
var subBtn = document.getElementById("subBtn");
var terminate = new Date("November 05, 2019 22:00:00");
//
function start() {
  checkForExpiration();
}
//
function checkForExpiration() {
  expMsg.innerHTML = "";
  subBtn.disabled = false;
  var currentDate = new Date();
  //
  if (currentDate > terminate) {
    subBtn.disabled = true;
    expMsg.innerHTML = "Sorry, but I said send the homework before 10pm today. You are too late.";
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
//
window.onload = start();</script>
```

Comment: You'd have to simply not serve the file at all until the desired time, or at the minimum use more obscure filenames. However, it would really help to include the code that is turning the links on and off.

Comment: If `18BEwW16.html` is a static html then it limits your options. You can add some random string to that file name to make it unguessable.

Comment: If you're going to be hard coding dates, at least hard code them as numbers, not strings, e.g. (`new Date(2019, 10, 5, 22, 0, 0)` for November 5, 2019 22:00:00; JavaScript months are zero-based). Different browsers interpret strings passed to `new Date()` differently.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing this is not meant to be terribly secure -- it would be trivial to turn in homework late using this JavaScript.

Comment: No, security is not a big issue on a homework page. Just out of interest, how would you do that?